# R: How to add a new column to an existing dataframe ONLY for a subset of rows and with a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I would like to add a new column, called "real_rt" based on values from another columns.

The columns of interest in the dataframe are:

- trial_type: values 'go' and 'nogo'
- StimOnset: numeric values
- RT: numeric values

"Real_rt" should be based on a subtraction of RT from StimOnset ONLY IF the value in RT > 0 (otherwise it should stay 0).
However, this calculation should be performed ONLY for the go trials (column "trail_type").

I know how to add a new column and how to make a for-loop and an if-statemanet (bc I think this is what I need here), but I don't know how to combine those 3 in order to get what I want. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use mutate in connection with case_when from the tidyverse package for this kind of thing:

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(StimOnset = c(1, 0, 2, 4),
                 RT = c(2, -1, 0, 5),
                 trial_type = c("go", "nogo", "go", "nogo"))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
   Real_rt = case_when(
     trial_type == "go" & RT > 0 ~ StimOnset - RT,
     TRUE ~ 0
    )
  )
df
StimOnset RT trial_type Real_rt
1         1  2         go      -1
2         0 -1       nogo       0
3         2  0         go       0
4         4  5       nogo       0
```

Comment: It worked out well, but I wonder if there's a way to leave the 'nogo' cells empty?

Comment: nvm, I figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

This should probably lead you in the right direction.

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 0, 2, 4),
                 Y = c(2, -1, 0, 5))

df$Z <- ifelse(df$Y > 0, df$X - df$Y, 0)
df
#  X  Y  Z
#1 1  2 -1
#2 0 -1  0
#3 2  0  0
#4 4  5 -1
```

Comment: Yeah, parenthetically, it's amazing how many people automatically rely on for and while loops in R when the language is designed to minimize them.

Comment: @SteveM Agreed.  We're all guilty of it when we were new, I'd imagine.  But once you realize about the benefits of vectorization, it's like being struck by lightning.

Comment: Yeah, I was lucky that I taught myself R via the free Johns Hopkins Data Science specialization on Coursera that points you to the great interactive swirl tutorials.  Nary a for or a while among them.

Comment: @Balter It certainly does, but any ideas how to limit this calculation to the rows that contain 'go' values in the trial_type column?

Comment: @PaulaH without seeing your data, it's hard to code it.  But what it sounds like you want is something like this:  `ifelse(df$trial_type == 'go' & df$RT > 0, df$StimOnset - df$RT, 0)`.

Comment: @PaulaH `ifelse()` is structured like this:  `ifelse(CONDITION, TRUE, FALSE)`, so you set your condition(s) in the first argument, then what you want to happen if true in the second one, and finally the third one is if that condition is false.  Which here, I'm just outputting a value of 0.

Comment: @Balter It worked out well, but I wonder if there's a way to leave the 'nogo' cells empty?

Comment: @Balter nvm, I figured out what to do! Thanks a lot!